# How to replace all fragments in FragmentPageAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am implementing swipable tab pages with PageViewer and FragmentPageAdapter.
I want to change all the fragments after login.

```
public class TabFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements   FragmentChangeListener {
    TabFragment tabFragment[];
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    boolean mNeedRefresh = false;

    public TabFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tabFragment = new TabFragment[4];
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        Log.d(this.toString(), "getItem:position="+position);
        if (position<0 || position>getCount())
            return null;

        if (tabFragment[position]==null) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                tabFragment[position] = MapFragment.newInstance(this, position);
                break;
            default:
                tabFragment[position] = BeforeLoginFragment.newInstance(this, position);
                break;
            }
        }

        return tabFragment[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) { 
        Log.d(this.toString(), "getItemPosition:object="+object.toString());

        int tabPosition = ((TabFragment)object).getTabPosition();
        //if (mNeedRefresh && ((TabFragment)object).getFragmentClassName() != tabFragment[tabPosition].getFragmentClassName()) {
        if (((TabFragment)object).getFragmentClassName() == tabFragment[tabPosition].getFragmentClassName()) {
            Log.d(this.toString(), "POSITION_UNCHANGED");
            return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
        } else {
            mNeedRefresh = false;
            Log.d(this.toString(), "POSITION_NONE");
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginChangeRequest() {
        Log.d(this.toString(), "onLoginChangeRequest");
        FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        for (int i=1; i<getCount(); i++)
        {
            transaction.remove(tabFragment[i]);

            switch (i) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
                tabFragment[i] = MapFragment.newInstance(this, i);
                break;
            case 3:
                tabFragment[i] = MapFragment.newInstance(this, i);
                break;
            }
        }
        transaction.commit();
        mNeedRefresh = true;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }   
}

public class RegisterStep03Fragment extends TabFragment implements OnClickListener, OnTaskCompleted {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String items[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.item_array_gender);

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.completeButton:
            RegisterNewUser();
        }
    }

    private void RegisterNewUser() {
        DownloadJSONObjectAsyncTask task = new DownloadJSONObjectAsyncTask();
        task.setOnTaskCompletedListener(this);

        task.execute(...);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONObject jsonObj) {
        try {
            if (jsonObj.getString("result").equals("success")) {
                getListener().onLoginChangeRequest();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I call "RegisterNewUser" method in the above source code, following error occurs.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:651)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:892)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2805)
    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
    at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
    at com.flagmon.adapter.TabFragmentPagerAdapter.onLoginChangeRequest(TabFragmentPagerAdapter.java:132)
    at com.flagmon.fragment.RegisterStep03Fragment.onTaskCompleted(RegisterStep03Fragment.java:189)
    at com.flagmon.task.DownloadJSONObjectAsyncTask.onPostExecute(DownloadJSONObjectAsyncTask.java:38)
    at com.flagmon.task.DownloadJSONObjectAsyncTask.onPostExecute(DownloadJSONObjectAsyncTask.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the source code like below. It seems like I have forgot to check the fragment that I want to change have been initialized.

```
public void onLoginChangeRequest() {
    Log.d(this.toString(), "onLoginChangeRequest");
    FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    for (int i=1; i<getCount(); i++)
    {
        if (tabFragment[i] != null) {

            transaction.remove(tabFragment[i]);

            switch (i) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
                tabFragment[i] = MapFragment.newInstance(this, i);
                break;
            case 3:
                tabFragment[i] = MapFragment.newInstance(this, i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    transaction.commit();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```